# HTML input: How to change word format depending on the word

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I want to have an input field that formats the text that get put into it dynamically. For example I want that every word that begins with an hashtag get turned in bold text. More precisely if I write *#todolist some task* than this text should instantly look like this ***#todolist** some task*

Initially I tried the `<input>` and the `<textarea>` elements, but that dit not work at all. I figured out that there is an attribute called `contenteditable` which allows to edit text inside a `<div>`. But I wonder if there is a better solution instead of using a `<div>` element?

Comment: let me confirm, so you just want to bold the text that starts with #. right?

Comment: You cannot edit the unique style of specific words in a input or textarea. Instead you must use or make a custom input field that wraps the words in Dom Elements.

Comment: @ZiaAhmad right

Comment: well i am trying to make something like that but you know m not a pro either : D

Comment: well i wrote a little snipper but problem is that you can only output it, i am not able make it bold inside the contenteditable div but programmed it to output on each input, other than that it works like u said, any word starting with # will be bold

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, general `<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>` and all the other default editable elements are not able to have any other child elements, thus, you can not do the text bold (`<b>`) or italic (`<em>`).

The best solution is a `<div>` with `contenteditable` attribute.

The article more on the `contenteditable`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

Comment: With `contenteditable` you're entering in the realm of contenteditable and all its quirks and nuisances. inner paragraphing, spanning, CTRL+B just to name a few...

Comment: That is a good point @RokoC.Buljan. Do you may konw a better way than using `contenteditable`?

Comment: @NiklasWeber unfortunately, I have no hands-on experience on such libraries or something. But maybe preventing the default events could be an option.

Answer (score 0):

The value of input or textarea is DOMString.

> Value: A DOMString representing the text contained in the text field. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text)

and you can not style (e.g. set font-weight) two-parted text without wrapping it in a DOM element.

Here is another idea which is also feasible:
You can set two input elements side by side, hide all of the native input stylesheet traces, and listen for onChagne values if it starts with `#` or anything more specific, you can change the style of the first input to **bold** or any other thing. Then blur the first input and focus on the second input.

there are lots of concerns you should take responsibility for now:

1. cross-browser UI compatibility for your inputs.
2. handle UI edge cases for the value that doesn't start with `#` (maybe setting the width of next input to 0 then).
3. 60 fps animation rate (or UI decomposition) for blur/focus effect.
4. keyboard will face a flash of close-open in this switching (blur/focus).